# How to get string resources from a certain file?

Tags: android, android-resources

I have two resources file in res/values directory: string.xml and names.xml

how can I retreive all resources from names.xml only

the method

```
Field[] x=R.string.class.getFields();
```

retrieves resources from both files.

how can this be acheived

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, but that is not possible. It does not matter that you have your strings split between multiple named resource files -- Android combines them all when it compiles your project.

You are welcome to use prefixes or something to identify one set of strings from another. I do that with the support code for [the Android Parcel Project](http://andparcel.com), to allow reusable components to each define strings without one overwriting the strings of another.

Comment: Thanks
you are right.
I used prefixes to distinguish between resources